# Voice recognition without Grammar file

Tags: c#, speech-to-text

I'm trying to use .Net's Speech Recognition feature to convert words to text. Although, everywhere I've seen is using a Grammar file. Is there a way that I can detect speech without one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to convert text to speech using the .NET frameworks Speech Recognition feature without a grammar file, because without one it doesn't know that what you're saying is a word.

It's like speaking in another language, if you don't know the language, how can you be sure they're even saying legitimate words? They could be speaking complete gibberish, so you don't listen to it.

Comment: Is there a way that I can load the English language that comes with Windows, and make it detect words from that? Because I need for it to be able to recognize different variables which I won't know the values of.

Comment: @user3629667 I don't believe there is, I think it is hard coded into the program.